# Javascript - different timestamp values on the same client

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, timestamp

Can someone please explain why these 3 different lines that suppose to produce the exact same result, give three different results?

The only accurate one is the 2'nd line (**Date.now()**). Unfortunately, this is the only one I can't use.

```js
function show_ts_date(idx, ts)
{
     var a = new Date(ts * 1000);
     var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
     var year = a.getFullYear();
     var month = months[a.getMonth()];
     var date = a.getDate();
     var hour = a.getHours();
     var min = a.getMinutes();
     var sec = a.getSeconds();
     var formattedTime = date + ' ' + month + ' ' + year + ' ' + hour + ':' + min + ':' + sec ;

     alert(idx+'. timestamp: '+ts+' Date: '+formattedTime);
}

var currentdate = new Date(); 

//line 1: (produces wrong timestamp - it gives the wrong hour (-4) when I convert back to dateTime)
timestamp_1 = Math.floor(new Date(currentdate.getFullYear()+'-'+(currentdate.getMonth()+1)+'-'+currentdate.getDate()+'T'+currentdate.getHours()+':'+currentdate.getMinutes()+':00') / 1000); 
show_ts_date(1, timestamp_1);


//line 2 (produces correct timastamp - it gives the correct hour when I convert back to DateTime.)
timestamp_2 = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000); 
show_ts_date(2, timestamp_2);


//line 3 (produces wrong timestamp - it gives the wrong hour (+3) when I convert back to dateTime)
let dat = new Date(Date.UTC(currentdate.getFullYear(), currentdate.getMonth(), currentdate.getDate(), currentdate.getHours(), currentdate.getMinutes(), 00));
timestamp_4 = Math.floor( dat/ 1000);
show_ts_date(4, timestamp_4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming that Date.now() returns the real accurate value (I doubt it is always the case, But that's what I'm left with. you can always convert it back to Date and check if the right date & time came back),
I wrote this function that will compare between the right and wrong timestamps and will add (or decrease) the number of milliseconds from (or to) the false timestamp - turning it in to a correct one:

```
function getTimestampMilisecondsGap()
{
        var currentdate = new Date(); 
        timestamp_1 = Math.floor(new Date(currentdate.getFullYear()+'-'+(currentdate.getMonth()+1)+'-'+currentdate.getDate()+'T'+currentdate.getHours()+':'+currentdate.getMinutes()+':00') / 1000); 
        //let dat = new Date(Date.UTC(currentdate.getFullYear(), currentdate.getMonth(), currentdate.getDate(), currentdate.getHours(), currentdate.getMinutes(), 00));
    //timestamp_1 = Math.floor( dat/ 1000);
    timestamp_2 = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000); //this one is suppose to produce a correct timestamp
    var addTimeStampMilisecs = 0;
    if (timestamp_2 > timestamp_1)
    {
        addTimeStampMilisecs = timestamp_2-timestamp_1;
    }
    else if (timestamp_2 < timestamp_1)
    {
        addTimeStampMilisecs = timestamp_1-timestamp_2;
    }
    return addTimeStampMilisecs;
}



//writing a timestamp to the database
var destinationDateTimeStr = document.getElementById("dateyear").value+"-"+document.getElementById("datemonth").value+"-"+document.getElementById("dateday").value+"T"+document.getElementById("datehour").value+":"+document.getElementById("dateminute").value+":00";

var date2 = new Date(destinationDateTimeStr);

var eventDateTS = Math.floor(date2 / 1000); //convert to timestamp (with incorrect timezone)
eventDateTS += getTimestampMilisecondsGap(); //add (or decrese) the number of miliseconds from the timestamp because this function that generates the tmestamp returns a wrong number (the hour in the converted date is wrong)

//write the correct eventDateTS to your DB here...
```